# DataGrid header should be Unchecked even if one of it's child items are Unchecked

Tags: wpf, datagrid, checkbox

[image]This is my first post here.

The problem i'm stuck with is related to checkbox in DataGrid(WPF). 
Sorry i could not attach the screenshot for better understanding of the problem as i'm a new user.

Problem: The DataHeader Column Checkbox is checked even when one of the child is Unchecked. 
I expect the solution to fix this so that when one of the child is unchecked explictly by the user, The ALL(Header) should be unchecked implicitely.

Please help guys... Thank You!

Plz check the link. i want the solution to work like this. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42437/Toggling-the-States-of-all-CheckBoxes-Inside-a-Dat#

Comment: Can you add your Xaml for DataGrid? I didn't quite understand your problem

Comment: @Nikolay: <dg:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Check}" IsThreeState="True" Width="50" >
                        <dg:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:Name="dtAllChkBx">
                                <CheckBox Name="cbxAll" Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.lblAll}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </dg:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    </dg:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

Comment: So you can just manually set header checkbox to Checked or Unchecked on Checked handler of your grid checkboxes if you use event handlers. Or if you use bindings then you can bind header checkbox to some property AllChecked and implement it in you DataContext class

Comment: @Nikolay My DataGrid contains 4 columns. the 1st column is d Checkbox header(cbxAll)(parent header). If i check tat, all the childs in datagrid r getting selected and same applies for uncheck as well. but the problem is after the above operation if i uncheck one of the child, the parent header is not getting Unchecked. it's a defect. any help? Assume i've 4 child details displayed, if one of d child is unchecked(all others r checked), the parent combobox selection should be Unchecked. that's it.

Comment: @nikolay: If i share d screenshot u'll better understand the problem. but i cannot as i'm a new user, still i dont have privilage to upload pics.

Answer (score 1):

I've sugested that you have a view that bind to viewmodel. In my code this viewmodel have a collection of Elements that binds to gridview ItemsSource and property HeaderChecked that represents state of the column header. Every Element has a proprety IsChecked. Sure ViewModel supports INotifyPropertyChanged.

This is a code of **ViewModel** (DataEventsSource just implements INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
public class MainViewModel : DataEventsSource
{
    private ObservableCollection<Element> _elements = new ObservableCollection<Element>
                                                          {
                                                              new Element {IsChecked = false},
                                                              new Element {IsChecked = false},
                                                              new Element {IsChecked = false},
                                                              new Element {IsChecked = false}
                                                          };

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        foreach (var element in _elements)
        {
            element.PropertyChanged += OnElementPropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
        {
            bool? headerChecked = null;
            if (Elements.All(el => el.IsChecked))
            {
                headerChecked = true;
            }
            if (Elements.All(el => !el.IsChecked))
            {
                headerChecked = false;
            }

            HeaderChecked = headerChecked;
        }

    }

    public ObservableCollection<Element> Elements
    {
        get
        {
            return _elements;
        }
        set
        {
            _elements = value;
        }
    }

    private bool? _headerChecked = false;
    public bool? HeaderChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _headerChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            _headerChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HeaderChecked");
        }
    }
}

public class Element : DataEventsSource
{
    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _isChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }
}
```

When element of collection is changed, as you see, HeaderChecked property is updated in the OnElementPropertyChanged method.

And this is the view:

**Codebehind**:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _viewModel = new MainViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }

    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var element in _viewModel.Elements)
        {
            element.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }

    private void CheckBox_UnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var element in _viewModel.Elements)
        {
            element.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And next the main grid from **XAML** (it contains only one column for simplicity):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="checkboxColumn" Binding="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsThreeState="True" Width="50"  >
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="dtAllChkBx">
                        <CheckBox Name="cbxAll" Content="Label" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.HeaderChecked, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"  Unchecked="CheckBox_UnChecked"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I hope this code will help you, if i misunderstood you, please let me know.

Comment: public class EnggLst : ObservableCollection<EnggLst>
    {
        public bool Check { get; set; }
    }

Comment: In that 2 events, I am using CellTemplate for checking all checkbox when Header checkbox is checked & unchecked.

But How to retrive the checkbox of header template of tht GridViewColumn to make the invert event, means unchecked any one checkbox of CellTemplate from the list, I want to uncheck the Header Checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

```
//this event is for **Checked and UnChecked** of up check box (cbxall)
private void UpCheckbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //checkBox1 = cbxall (your up checkbox)
    if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true)
    {
        dataGrid1.Items.OfType<YourClass>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsChecked = true);
    }
    else
    {
        dataGrid1.Items.OfType<YourClass>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsChecked = false);
    }
}

//this event is for all other check box
//**Checked and UnChecked** of all other check box is this event
private void OtherCheckbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //checkBox1 = cbxall (your up checkbox)
    if (dataGrid1.Items.OfType<YourClass>().All(x => x.IsChecked == true))
    {
        checkBox1.IsChecked = true;
    }
    else if (dataGrid1.Items.OfType<YourClass>().All(x => x.IsChecked == false))
    {
        checkBox1.IsChecked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        checkBox1.IsChecked = null;
    }
}
```

...